# Malformed string exception while sending "&" in Json to AppEngine

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, post, encoding, windows-phone-8

I am trying to send Facebook graph link to the AppEngine server. I receive "Malformed string exception". Here is my method sending json to server:

```
public async Task<string> SendJSONData(string urlToCall, string JSONData)
    {
        // server to POST to
        string url = urlToCall;

        // HTTP web request
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        // Write the request Asynchronously 
        using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,
                                                                 httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
        {
            //create some json string
            string json = "action=" + JSONData;

            // convert json to byte array
            byte[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            // Write the bytes to the stream
            await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
        }

        WebResponse response = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        StreamReader requestReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        String webResponse = requestReader.ReadToEnd();
        return webResponse; }
```

Here is what I sniff using Fiddler:

```
POST http://x.appspot.com/register HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 376
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: NativeHost
Host: x.appspot.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

action={
  "mailFb": "mail@gmail.com",
  "userName": "Michael",
  "userSurname": "w00t",
  "nickname": "Michael w00t",
  "userSex": "male",
  "userAvatar": "https://graph.facebook.com/myperfectid/picture?type=large&access_token=BlahblahblahblahToken"
}
```

So everything looks fine, but the problem is that i receive the following error in AppEngine log:

```
2013-03-02 17:52:10.431 /register 500 56ms 0kb NativeHost
W 2013-03-02 17:52:10.427 /register com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 7 column 79 at com.google.g
C 2013-03-02 17:52:10.429 Uncaught exception from servlet com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 7 colu
```

I managed to narrow the problem to its source, which is "&" character. So my question is, how to fix the code, so that it works with AppEngine.
Oh, here is how i read the received data on the server:

```
gson.fromJson(reader, User.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is highlighted by the fact you're claiming you are sending "`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`"
But it isn't.  Hence the error.

The correct encoding for `&` is `&amp;`.